# How to call a function by pressing enter key in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var input = document.getElementById("search");
function showTrue() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "It's  true";
}
function showFalse() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "It's  false";
}
// Get the input field


// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Cancel the default action, if needed
  event.preventDefault();
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    showFalse();
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="author" content="colorlib.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,800" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js">

    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:black">
    <div class="s006">
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>What are you looking for?</legend>
          <div class="inner-form">
            <div class="input-field">
              <button id="trueButton" onclick="showTrue()" class="btn-search" type="button">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
              <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Test you news here" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
        <p style="font-size: 36px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 800;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 59px;" id="output"></p>
      </form>




    </div>

  </body><!-- This templates was made by Colorlib (https://colorlib.com) -->
</html>
```

I want on pressing enter button it should display that `it's flase` but then on pressing enter button it first displays the output and then refreshes the page any idea why and suggestion what shoud I do to prevent it ?

I just want that when enter key is pressed it should display the out below the search field that 'it's false'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page will be replaced when the *keypress* event's default action goes through, so you need to add a listener to `keypress` events and call `.preventDefault()` on them as well when `enter` is pressed. (`keyup` events don't need `preventDefault()` for anything, AFAIK)

There's another problem, though; it looks like your `script` tag is in the `head` and doesn't wait for the document to be populated to run. Give it the `defer` attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" defer>
```

When a script tag has the `defer` attribute, it will wait for the document to be loaded before running.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("search");

function showTrue() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "It's  true";
}

function showFalse() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "It's  false";
}
// Get the input field


input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    showFalse();
  }
});
```

```html
<body style="background-color:black">
  <div class="s006">
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>What are you looking for?</legend>
        <div class="inner-form">
          <div class="input-field">
            <button id="trueButton" onclick="showTrue()" class="btn-search" type="button">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
            <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Test you news here" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
      <p style="font-size: 36px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 800;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 59px;" id="output"></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null also it's still refreshing

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" for a live demo - as you can see, it should be working perfectly fine.

Comment: It looks like your `script` tag is in the `head` and doesn't wait for the document to be populated to run. Give it the `defer` attribute. `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" defer>`

Comment: yeah that was the error only thanks it solved add it to answer and can you explain what defer does

Comment: But now after adding defer I am unable to input in my search box you can see it here https://vivanks.github.io/HoaxDetection/?

Comment: For the input to be populated, in the `keypress` listener, call `preventDefault` when the `keyCode` is 13